# Is it possible to determine the Geolocation method used?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, cllocationmanager

I am using CLLocationManager to get location updates in my app. Is there a way to determine what the GeoLocation method was? E.g. GPS, Triangulation, IP (Network).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. You can take a look at the `horizontalAccuracy` of a CLLocation object and hazard a guess based on its value, though:

- < 25 meters: probably GPS
- < 200 meters: probably Wi-Fi
- anything greater: probably cell-tower triangulation

These values are just off the top of my head—to be most accurate you’ll probably want to do some experimentation yourself.

edit - also worth noting is that determining the device you’re running on can give you more information about which location provider is being used. For instance, first-gen iPhones had no GPS, so if you’re running on one of those then your location is definitely coming from either cell towers or Wi-Fi; no iPod model to date has supported anything other than Wi-Fi triangulation; and only the 3G model of the iPad has ever had cell-tower triangulation and GPS.